# How to change the font in SmartSVN?

Tags: windows-7, gui, user-interface, user-experience, smartsvn

Using SmartSVN on my Windows machine, it is not honoring my Windows font preferences (neither font size or font face). They should be doing something like:

```
void GetIconTitleFont(ref string fontName, ref int fontHeight)
{
    if (SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETICONTITLELOGFONT, SizeOf(logfont), logfontf, 0)
    {
       fontName = lfFaceName;
       fontHeight = lfHeight;
    }
    else
    {
        faceName = "Segoe UI";
        fontHeight = -9 * ScreenDpiY/96;
    }
}
```

But instead the SmartSVN gui-font <sub><sub><sub><sub>is hard-coded to a really really tiny font.</sub></sub></sub></sub>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to edit `smartsvn.properties` under your Application Data area (at least it is in Windows XP) and add the following two lines:

```
smartsvn.lookAndFeel.usePlatformIndependent=true  
smartsvn.ui.fontsize=14
```

Comment: i'm going to accept this answer without testing it. i gave up on SmartSVN because of the horrible UI.